# Is there any way to slow down future or set min. duration execution of future in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to slow down all futures in app without touching one by one. like slow down animation in flutter work.

example. like I have built app and in data layer all futures are executed within sec. I need to something to slow down all futures in app, like in flutter dev tools we can slow down animations, we can do one by one that's not problem but need something that trigged slow down all future.

Ex.
Future work() {} it executed within mili sec. in dev env.
in live env. work() will executed withing 5 sec.
I need something to slow down work() to specific duration. like wait for 5 sec then executed, we can do one by one. but, is there any way to do all at once like flutter slow animation works.

Comment: try Future.await

Comment: this is slowest way, I need something like slowing animation done in flutter works

Comment: Most futures are triggered from network events, not a time duration. How do you propose to slow those down?

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: If you are using animations the animation have whenComplete action then you can trigger a funtion you need or call

Comment: example. like I have built app and in data layer all futures are executed within sec. I need to something to slow down all futures in app, like in flutter dev tools we can slow down animations, we can do one by one that's not problem but need something that trigged slow down all future